# Mirroring iPhone screen via browser

Tags: iphone, web-browser, mirroring

Is there a tool that could be used to mirror an iPhone screen via browser.

What i need is to provide someone a URL and when that URL is opened in browser he could see a mirroring of my iPhone?

Couldn't find anything when searching. Is anyone aware of such a tool that could help achieve screen mirroring via browser?

I have been doing this for Android using [Vysor](http://www.vysor.io/). Unable to find a similar one for iOS (if one exists)

Answer (score 2):

This is a little dated, and it might not be *exactly* what you wanted, but it still should work.  There's no simple way of doing this.  You'll need to get an app named [**Reflector**](https://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector) and **Google Hangouts**, **Skype**, or **iMessages** to share your screen.  Here's the link to the site I found this but I'll also list out the steps in case the link goes down: http://mgalligan.com/post/29978268510/screen-share-iphone-live-on-internet

- Download Reflector (this awesome app allows your computer to become an AirPlay compatible display)
- Activate Reflector - It’s simple. Just open your newly downloaded Reflector app, double-tap your iPhone’s home button, swipe left twice to show off the volume control and a small button to the right to share the screen. You should see “iPhone” or “iPad” depending on your device, and then the name of your computer below that. After tapping on the name of your computer, make sure “Mirroring” is ON. *Note*: You should now see your iPhone’s screen on your computer screen. Go ahead, test it out.
- Start a Google Hangout, Messages.app or Skype screen share. Note: if you’re using Google Hangouts and use multiple screens, make sure that your browser window with the chat in it is on the same screen as the Reflector app. Simply choose the Reflector app as your intended screen share and voila!